# Can't get iFrame body or scroll height in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, iframe, height

I am attempting to use the code below to get the height of content within an iFrame so I can resize the iFrame height to fit its content. However, when I run it I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'body').

Why can't seem to access the iFrame body?

**HTML**

```
<template>
  <div class="iframe-container">
    <iframe src={url} onload={handleLoad} style={iframeStyle}></iframe>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Javascript**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class IframeExample extends LightningElement {
  @track url = 'https://www.example.com';
  @track iframeStyle = 'height: 0px;';

  handleLoad() {
    const iframe = this.template.querySelector('iframe');
    const iframeHeight = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    this.iframeStyle = `height: ${iframeHeight}px;`;
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.iframe-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 aspect ratio */
  height: 0;
}

.iframe-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```